# Load image after an alertbox

Tags: javascript

I want to load an image if I clicked on "OK" in my alert box.
I've made a Quiz, so if you click on answer "B", you get a alert box with "This is the right answer!, you have now unlocked a new image!" en after that, show the actual image in my div or something like that.

This is what I have:

```
function buttonClick() {
    if (document.getElementById("option1").checked == true) { 
        alert("Wrong, the answer was B");
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("option2").checked == true) { 
        alert("This is the right answer!, you have now unlocked a new image!, click OK to see it");
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("option3").checked == true) { 
        alert("Wrong, the answer was B");
    }
    else {
        alert("Choose an answer")
    }
}
```

My HTML

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="groter" value="97" id="option1"   >A. 97 keer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="groter" value="79" id="option2"   >B. 79 keer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="groter" value="21" id="option3"   >C. 21 keer<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="buttonClick()">Controleer</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `if` block with the right answer, simply create an image element and append it:

```
var myImg = document.createElement("img");
myImg.src = "path to your image";
document.getElementById("yourContainer").appendChild(myImg);
```

Comment: It works! thanks! But if I want to edit the style of the image, how is that possible in CSS?

Comment: Is it possible to fade it in using jQuery? I'm new to this :S

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as:

Add the following to your html

```
<div id="img-holder">
</div>
```

And your js; add to your correct case, after the alert...

```
// Make ur img obj here...
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'image path here';
document.getElementById("img-holder").appendChild(img);
```